# Integral of the Laplacian of a function that is constant on the sphere

Tags: laplacian, divergence-operator, multiple-integral

Take $B^n=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|x|<1\}$.

Let $f(x)=(|x|^2-1)^{20}\sin(x_1+\cdots+x_n)$.

Find the integral 
$$\int\limits_{B^n}\Delta f(x)dx$$

I took $S^n=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|x|=1\}$ and said that $\partial B^n=S^n$.

The function seems arbitrary to me, so I wanted to use the divergence theorem to say that

$$\int\limits_{B^n}\Delta f(x)dx=\int\limits_{S^n}\langle\nabla f,N\rangle dS=\int\limits_{S^n}0\ dS=0$$

Since $\Delta f=\text{div}(\nabla f)$ and $f(x)=0$ is constant when $x\in S^n$, so $\langle\nabla f,N\rangle=0$, too.

Is it true?

**Edit**: I understand what the comments are saying. But,

$$\nabla f_i=20(|x|^2-1)^{19}(2x_i)\sin(x_1+\cdots+x_n)+(|x|^2-1)^{20}\cos(x_1+\cdots+x_n)$$

So, $\nabla f_i=0$ in $S^n$, no?

Comment: As $n_f=\nabla f$ is the normal to the surface $f(x) =0$. You should obtain the result $\int_{S^n} \langle n_f, n_S \rangle dS \neq 0$ with $n_S$ the normal to the sphere.

Comment: @Fabian I understand what you are saying. But can you please see my edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $f(x)=0$ is constant when $x\in S^n$, so $\langle\nabla f,N\rangle=0$,
>   too.

$f(x)=0$ being constant when $x\in S^n$ tells you that $\langle\nabla f,v\rangle=0$ for vectors $v$ that are *tangent* to the sphere - specifically not the normal vector.

Now given the edit, that makes more sense. I can't see any flaw. But the point is not that the function is constant on the sphere, rather that its derivatives vanish in *all* directions.

Comment: I understand. But can you please see my edit?

Comment: @TrueTopologist yes. I agree now.